# Origin of the word Mathematics and in which condition it did come of?

Tags: math-history

From which word, Mathematics has come from? Just tried to know. Help me out to know that. Also let me know the literature-change of this term.

Comment: Bourbaki invented it so they could omit the "s".

Comment: It is mentioned in the Wikipedia article for mathematics in the first paragraph or so.

Comment: Try also http://hsm.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematics comes from the Greek word  μάθημα (máthēma) which means "that which is learnt".